# extrude along normals going wrong

Tags: modeling, normals, extrude

I try to extrude the faces here:
[image]

But it get weird and uniform like this:

[image]

I make sure that I apply scale and make even offset, but it's the same.
I want to extrude like the other faces that I extrude using bridge edge loop. But this method is taking a lot of work and making shading issues that should correct it by weighted normal, etc.

So is there any quick way to right extrude?